# Can't handle my leopard gecko after trying many different techniques

Tags: leopard-geckos, animal-handling

I have an adult female leopard gecko (a year old) and a young male leopard gecko (1 month old). The older one struggled with post traumatic stress being handled but still lets me pet her and sometimes even sits on my hand when my hand is flat down in her cage. The younger male has a neurological disorder (wobbles or falls when extremely stressed) but he's doing alright with taming.

Recently, I went to try different methods of picking them up since I thought they would be ready for it but instead I stressed them out and now have to start from square one. I've done a lot of research on how to handle/pick them up but it doesn't seem to be working as they're both too jumpy once I lift them up from my hand but they act quite calm with anything else.

**Is there possibly any advice that could resolve this issue?**

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange :)